# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '() -> Data?'

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am having an issue where I want to upload an image to the Firebase storage/database. I am receiving this issue when I create this line of code:

```
if let uploadData = UIImage.pngData(self.profileImage.image!) {
}
```

The error for this line is as the title states: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '() -> Data?'

Any suggestions for how to remedy this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
guard let uploadData = profileImage.image?.pngData() else { return }
```

if you need if let

```
if let uploadData = profileImage.image?.pngData() {

}
```

`pngData()` is an instance method of `UIImage` instance

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624096-pngdata

in your code you consider it a class method which isn't correct